# In Julia, how to define operator for more than 2 structs?

Tags: struct, macros, julia, operators

In Julia, I have my own struct, say `MyNumber`. I would like to define an operator, e.g. the product operator `*`, for my struct. The following is what I tried.

```py
struct MyNumber
    name::String
    value::Int
end

x1 = MyNumber("postive", 4)
x2 = MyNumber("postive", 3)

# define product operator for MyNumber
a::MyNumber * b::MyNumber = MyNumber("no_name", a.value + b.value)

y = x1*x2
println(y) # ok here, output: MyNumber("no_name", 7)
```

It works very well. However, when I try I apply the product for more than 2 inputs, e.g. `z=x1*x2*x1*x2*x2`, I got error. How do I deal with such case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the correct way of defining the `*` operator for a custom data type:

```
import Base.:*

struct MyNumber
    name::String
    value::Int
end

x1 = MyNumber("postive", 4)
x2 = MyNumber("postive", 3)

# define product operator for MyNumber
Base.:*(a::MyNumber, b::MyNumber)::MyNumber = MyNumber("no_name", a.value + b.value)

y = x1*x2
println(y) # ok here, output: MyNumber("no_name", 7)
```

The operator should be imported from the Base package explicitly.

Edit: Since I have used the `Base.:*` in the method definition, it is not needed to import the operator explicitly as mentioned below.

Comment: `import Base.:*` is not needed in this case as you prefix it with `Base.` anyway when defining a method.

Comment: yes, sorry, the first line is not really required as I defined the method explicitly with the Base.:*

Answer (score 5):

To add to the answer by jbytecode , the reason your original code does not work is because you are defining a new function `*` in the Main module instead of extending the `Base.:*` function .

`Base.:*` has many methods one of which handles expressions like `a*b*c`.

The function you defined has only 1 method for `*(MyNumber,MyNumber)`

In-fact such a function definition before you run any * will break using * on other types further down in your code. (And if you did use * before defining your own * , Julia will ask you to import Base.:* to extend it)

Comment: merci and 1 up-vote!